Cannot kill Popen process
I have a Python program with the following structure and necessary imports:
def startLogger(logger_dir):
    command0 = 'adb logcat -c'
    command1 = 'adb logcat'
    command2 = 'python3 '+logger_dir+'main.py'

    clear_logcat = subprocess.run(command0.split())
    logcatHandle = subprocess.Popen(command1.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    loggerHandle = subprocess.Popen(command2.split(),stdin=logcatHandle.stdout,shell=False)
    return logcatHandle, loggerHandle

def closeLogger(logcatInstance, loggerInstance):
    loggerInstance.kill() #Killing it first so that it doesn't break the input PIPE
    logcatInstance.kill()
    return logcatInstance, loggerInstance

def main():
    logger_dir = '/Users/Desktop/logger/'
    print("Starting Logger")
    logcatHandle, loggerHandle = startLogger(logger_dir)
    time.sleep(10)
    logcat, logger = closeLogger(logcatHandle, loggerHandle)

main()

The code works fine, I can execute logcat on my Android device, pull in logs, and feed it to my logger giving me the desired output in a text file created by the logger file. But, I cannot kill both processes. I have tried the terminate() method, os.kill(process.pid, signam.SIGKILL), preexec_fn flag, os.killpg(), etc methods, but still, the logger keeps on running in the background. What can be the possible issue here?

Why create strings and split them (which will do the wrong thing when logger_dir has spaces in it) instead of just explicitly defining a list in the first place? (That is, f/e, command2 = ['python3', f'{logger_dir}/main.py'], and get rid of the split())

...more to the point, though -- what's the process state as shown by ps? There are very few circumstances under which a SIGKILL can be ignored -- one of those is if a process is invoking a hung syscall (meaning a kernel driver, a network filesystem, or so forth isn't behaving properly); in Linux, at least, that'll show up as a D state in ps.

Strangely it doesn't show up when i run ps, but the returncode still says "None" for both the open processes.

Ah! returncode == None doesn't necessarily mean it's still running, it just means Python didn't collect its return code to find out how it died. If you'd told us how/why you thought the program was still running we might have gotten to this solution much faster :)

Make sure you wait() for the process -- the way Python (or any other UNIX program) finds out how a subprocess exited is to call a waitpid()-family syscall, the return value for which describes how the program died.

@CharlesDuffy, yes it was my bad. But, i actually needed the returncode to be not None inside the program in order to perform other tasks, as if the logger was running, those tasks would be hindered leading to erroneous log entries.

You should ensure that you're properly closing pipe before killing the processes.
Also, instead of using "kill", use "terminate" to give the process a chance to clean up. If it doesn't, then use "kill".
Then, make sure that the subprocesses don't inherit unnecessary file descriptors which might keep them running.
Considering those changes, try with
import subprocess
import time
import os
import signal

def startLogger(logger_dir):
    command0 = 'adb logcat -c'
    command1 = 'adb logcat'
    command2 = 'python3 ' + logger_dir + 'main.py'

    
    clear_logcat = subprocess.run(command0.split())
    logcatHandle = subprocess.Popen(command1.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    loggerHandle = subprocess.Popen(command2.split(), stdin=logcatHandle.stdout, preexec_fn=os.setsid) #this starts each subrprocess in a new session
    return logcatHandle, loggerHandle

def closeLogger(logcatInstance, loggerInstance):
    loggerInstance.terminate()
    try:
        loggerInstance.wait(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        loggerInstance.kill()

    logcatInstance.terminate()
    try:
        logcatInstance.wait(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        logcatInstance.kill()
    
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(logcatInstance.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(loggerInstance.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
#(ensures all processes in the process group are terminated, handling any subprocesses that might have been spawned.)
    
    return logcatInstance, loggerInstance

def main():
    logger_dir = '/Users/Desktop/logger/'
    print("Starting Logger")
    logcatHandle, loggerHandle = startLogger(logger_dir)
    time.sleep(10)
    logcat, logger = closeLogger(logcatHandle, loggerHandle)
    print("Logger stopped")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Hope it helps.

Accepting this answer for now as it surprisingly worked! I added the process.wait() with a timeout and the try-catch blocks, which terminate the processes. The return code for the terminated process if -15. Can you possibly further explain to me which line exactly kills the PIPE and which line kills the file descriptors? Cheers!
